# C# Group nested lists

Tags: c#

I have a list of values like:

```
OrderId_1, Number_1, Date, ItemId, ItemName, ItemDesc, Address1Id Address1Zip, Address1City, Address2Id Address2Zip, Address2City
.
.
.
OrderId_n, Number_n, Date, ItemId, ItemName, ItemDesc, Address1Id Address1Zip, Address1City, Address2Id Address2Zip, Address2City
```

And i want to group them in nested objects like:

```
List<Order>
   Order: OrderId, Number, Date, ItemList, Address1, Address2
   ItemList: ItemId, ItemName, ItemDesc
   Address1: Address1Id Address1Zip, Address1City
   Address2: Address2Id Address2Zip, Address2City
```

I tried:

```
List<Order> list = orderFromDB.ToList()
                .GroupBy(a => a.OrderId)
                .Select(
                    g =>
                        new Order
                        {
                            OrderId = g.Key,
                            Number= g.Number, <<< No Number Property here
```

Sample:
I have the list:

```
OrderId1, Number1, Date1, ItemId1, ItemName1, ItemDesc1, Address1Id1 Address1Zip1, Address1City1, Address2Id1 Address2Zip1, Address2City1
OrderId1, Number1, Date1, ItemId2, ItemName2, ItemDesc2, Address1Id1 Address1Zip1, Address1City1, Address2Id1 Address2Zip1, Address2City1
OrderId1, Number1, Date1, ItemId3, ItemName3, ItemDesc3, Address1Id2 Address1Zip2, Address1City2, Address2Id2 Address2Zip2, Address2City2

To format it like:
OrderId1, Number1, Date1, 
                         Items as List<Items>: 
                                ItemId1, ItemName1, ItemDesc1
                                ItemId2, ItemName2, ItemDesc2
                                ...
                         Address1: Address1Id1, Address1Zip1, Address1City1
                         Address2: Address2Id2, Address2Zip2, Address2City2
.
.
. 
the other orders.
```

How may i group them as a list of Orders?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're looking for here. Please could you give a complete example rather than snippets, including a concrete example of the expected result?

Comment: What does your order class look like?

Comment: As i wrote: Order: OrderId, Number, Date, ItemList, Address1, Address2

Comment: A practical example in code would be helpful.  Do you have a list of lists?  Or is it a list of objects?  Please clarify.

Comment: i get a long list of string from DB and i have to split it in objects based on OrderId, ItemId and 2 AddressId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming (among a few other things) you can't fix the underlying data source, maybe:

```
class OrderItem
{
    public int OrderId;
    public int Number;
    public DateTime Date;
    public int ItemId;
    public string ItemName;
    public string ItemDesc;
    public string Address1Id;
    public string Address1Zip;
    public string Address1City;
    public string Address2Id;
    public string Address2Zip1;
    public string Address2City;
}
class Item
{
    public int ItemID;
    public string ItemName;
    public string ItemDesc;
}
class Address
{
    public string AddressId;
    public string AddressZip;
    public string AddressCity;
}
class Order
{
    public int OrderId;
    public int Number;
    public DateTime Date;
    public Address Address1;
    public Address Address2;
    public List<Item> Items;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<OrderItem> orderItems = new List<OrderItem>
    {
        new OrderItem()
        {
                OrderId = 1, Number=1, Date = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-11"),
                ItemId = 123, ItemName = "Name 123", ItemDesc = "Item 123",
                Address1Id = "1", Address1City = "New York", Address1Zip = "10001",
                Address2Id = "2", Address2City = "Boston", Address2Zip1 = "02101"
        }
    };

    var query = orderItems.GroupBy(o => new
    {
        o.OrderId,
        o.Number,
        o.Date,
        o.Address1City,
        o.Address1Id,
        o.Address1Zip,
        o.Address2City,
        o.Address2Id,
        o.Address2Zip1
    },
    (group, orders) => new Order
    {
        OrderId = group.OrderId,
        Number = group.Number,
        Date = group.Date,
        Address1 = new Address() { AddressCity = group.Address1City, AddressId = group.Address1Id, AddressZip = group.Address1Zip },
        Address2 = new Address() { AddressCity = group.Address2City, AddressId = group.Address2Id, AddressZip = group.Address2Zip1 },
        Items = (from o in orders select new Item() { ItemID = o.ItemId, ItemDesc = o.ItemDesc, ItemName = o.ItemName  }).ToList()
    });

    //do something with query
    return 0;
}
```

Code compiled, but not really tested.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is your architecture isn't good.

If I'm reading this, you've got:

- Items - consisting of an ID, name, description, and address to ship
  to.
- Orders - consists of an ID, a number, a date, and a collection of
  items.

Great!  So your classes should simply look like:

```
public class Order
{
    public int orderID;
    public string orderNumber;
    public DateTime orderDate;
    public List<Item> itemsInOrder;
}
public class Item
{
    public int itemID;
    public string name;
    public string description;
    public Address address;
}
public class Address
{
    public int addressID;
    public string zip;
    //etc
}
```

And your database backend should *also* have this sort of normalized structure.

Okay, so if your database backend isn't normalized, and all this data is just dumped into rows?

Then you're *still* going to want to at least have proper class structure in your C# layer.  Don't try to represent things as just a nested list of values.  Actually structure your data.

Maybe something like:

```
public class Order
{
    // same data properties as earlier code sample
    public static List<Order> GenerateFromRawDataLines(List<List<string>> rawData)
    {
        // do a linq GroupBy on rawData's orderID column
        // for each item in the GroupBy:
            // generate a new Order instance, populate its data members
            // for each item in the subgrouping:
                // add a new Item instance with an embedded Address instance.
    }
}
public class Item
{
    // same data properties as earlier code sample
    public Item(List<string> rawDataLine)
    {
        this.itemID = rawDataLine[3];
        this.name = rawDataLine[4];
        // etc - translating a raw List<string> of data values into a class instance
    }
}
```